# How to make embedded mongodb keep the data on application shutdown?

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot, embedded-database

I don't want to install the full mongodb, so I created a simple spring-boot application with the following pom:

```
    <!-- This dependency is to have an embedded mongodb -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>de.flapdoodle.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo</artifactId>
        <version>1.50.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- while this provides a spring factory bean for the embedded mongodb -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>cz.jirutka.spring</groupId>
        <artifactId>embedmongo-spring</artifactId>
        <version>RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- finally this one is the spring-boot starter for mongodb -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
     </dependency>
```

It works fine, but on the application shutdown **I lose all the data** stored.

I noticed that the db is created inside of a temporary folder under 
`C:\Users\myUser\AppData\Local\Temp\embedmongo-db-78beadc3-fa16-4101-afb1-ea7496f6f90c` and, every time the application is restarted, another folder with different ID is created at the same location.

So, would it be possible to specify where the DB should be created so to keep the existing one and not lose all the data? Like you would do with h2 or sqllite?

Comment: https://github.com/flapdoodle-oss/de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo/issues/206

Comment: Just out of curiosity: why choose a DBMS specifically designed to have dedicated multi-machine deployments for data sizes > what a single machine can store and _then_ use an embedded version of it? Even in unit-tests, this makes no sense, as DB should be mocked there (the "expected vs actual behaviour" thing, you know) and integration test environments should resemble the actual environment as closely as possible. Read: same version, same setup as in production, scaled smaller if necessary. Just asking...

Comment: Well, @MarkusWMahlberg, imagine a situation where your customer doesn't want to install any extra software on his environment for there are already too many things to take care of. And you want to use a database in your product very badly since it would make your work so much easier.

Comment: @LiebsterKamerad Sounds like „I want to have the cake and eat it.“ on both occasions. As for the customer, I do quite some requirements management, but that is a requirement I literally never came along. If a customer really wants a product, he is up to installing the prequisites. As for the developer, I would and do argue that it does not. Running a MongoDB instance using Docker for Desktop literally takes a single line `docker run -p 27017:27017 -n myMongo mongo` and does not introduce a dependency solely for the sake of convenience whilst removing flexibility and scalability.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg I do totally agree with you, but Docker is also not an immediately applicable option at least for some of our customers (for no other but purely bureaucratic reasons).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Now it's possible* see [it](https://github.com/flapdoodle-oss/de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo#custom-database-directory).

Next code just shows my solution to implement it.

```
public class MongoInMemory {
 private int port;
 private String host;
 private MongodProcess process = null;

 public MongoInMemory(int port, String host){
    this.port = port;
    this.host = host;
 }

 @PostConstruct
 public void init() throws IOException {
    Storage storage = new Storage(
            System.getProperty("user.home") + "/.ttraining-storage", null, 0);

    IRuntimeConfig runtimeConfig = new RuntimeConfigBuilder()
            .defaults(Command.MongoD)
            .artifactStore(new ExtractedArtifactStoreBuilder()
                    .defaults(Command.MongoD)
                    .download(new DownloadConfigBuilder()
                            .defaultsForCommand(Command.MongoD).build())
                    .executableNaming(new UserTempNaming()))
            .build();

    IMongodConfig mongodConfig = new MongodConfigBuilder()
            .version(Version.Main.PRODUCTION)
            .net(new Net(host, port, false))
            .replication(storage)
            .build();

    MongodStarter runtime = MongodStarter.getInstance(runtimeConfig);
    process = runtime.prepare(mongodConfig).start();
 }

 @PreDestroy
 public void stop(){
    process.stop();
 }
}
```

**In configuration class define that as a bean**

```
@Bean
public MongoInMemory mongoInMemory(
    @Value("${spring.data.mongodb.port}") int port,
    @Value("${spring.data.mongodb.host}")  String host) {
        return new MongoInMemory(port, host)
}
```

**At last, remove embedded mongodb autoconfiguration in your entry point**

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = EmbeddedMongoAutoConfiguration.class)
```

**PS**: Remove from dependecies *cz.jirutka.spring:embedmongo-spring*

**PSS**: Tested on Spring-boot 2.0.0.RELEASE

**PSSS**: Also you can define path as a property in application.properties and also it in constructor

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to set the database-dir and oplog-size of the embedded mongo-db in the application.properties as described here: http://sahits.ch/blog/openpatrician/2017/05/20/embedded-databases-for-statistic-storage/

```
spring.mongodb.embedded.storage.database-dir=your-dir-name
spring.mongodb.embedded.storage.oplog-size=0
```

I needed this as well and it works like a charm. Tested with spring-boot 2.2.5.RELEASE and de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo 2.2.0